# vue.js component using laravel blade for the template

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-blade, vue.js

My idea is to use laravel blade in the `<template></template>` of a vue/vueify component. I am not sure how to get the blade processor to run and output the html into the template inside the .vue file or in an imported template file.

Comment: That's a horrible idea. IDE will be mad. Compiler will be mad. And I really see no point in doing so. Why not just use .vue files for the sake of it?

Comment: Yeah I had not even tried it, I was stuck in the conceptual part.

Comment: You're stuck because this shouldn't be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the template inline then you can output whatever you want inside of it ( from your something.blade.php file ):

```
<super-duper-component inline-template >

{!! $some_php_variable_sent_to_the_view !!}

@{{ $data.someVueDataProperty | json }}

</super-duper-component>
```

You can use the blade `@include('path-to.super-duper-component')` to include this snippet from a simple `super-duper-component.blade.php` file so you can keep the component's template in one location for maintaining the template in the future.

Comment: I had not thought about including the vue into the blade... I will have to try that thanks

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe what he's trying to do is preposterous.

I find that there're things that Laravel blade does better than Vue and just want to get a prepared blade run template to be returned asynchronously using vue resource.

What you can do is actually make vue blade templates. That are actually then passed by Laravel via a route that returns a view that has vue code. That way it enables the user of blade templates to do what he does best in PHP and blade them return a good vue template that had code.